# Clojure - How to Declare a Collection or Vector of a Record

Tags: data-structures, clojure, record

How Can I define a Record Collection or a Vector of Records?

I have this snippet code:

`(defrecord Transaction [a, b, c])`

I want define a Transaction collection called LastTransactions to implement a function like this:

```
(defn can-authorize
    "Validate Authorization by Transaction"
    [^Transaction transaction, ^LastTransactions lastTransactions]
    (... business logic)
    )
```

First Question, is that the right way to do that?

Second, How can i declare that structure?

Comment: What do you mean by 'declare' the structure? Clojure doesn't have a static type system so just need to ensure you pass a vector as the second argument to `can-authorize`. You could define a spec or contract for the function if you want to check a vector is actually provided at runtime.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `^LastTransactions lastTransactions` rather than `^LastTransaction lastTransactions`? Also you probably don't want a record. In truth I'm not sure what their purpose is - you can just use a map. Then the 2nd argument will be a vector of maps.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Fixed

Comment: @Lee thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure's type hints don't offer any type validation - you can use [Clojure Spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) or [Plumatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) for that. They only serve for the compiler to prevent reflection when Java methods are called on the parameters. For that purpose, you don't need to type hint a vector since Clojure's core functions for collections (`first`, `conj`, etc.) by design don't require reflection on standard collections.

However, if you need, you can type-hint the elements that you extract from the `lastTransaction` sequence, for example:

```
(defn can-authorize
  "Validate Authorization by Transaction"
  [^Transaction transaction, lastTransactions]
  ...
  (for [^Transaction t lastTransactions]
    (...do-something-with t))
```

Comment: I'll do that. Thank You. 
i'm beginner at Clojure and learning how it's behave

Comment: What the main differences between Clojure Spec and Plumatic Schema?

Answer (score 0):

Type-hints are used to avoid reflection. They are not used to statically type function or constructor args.

Just use basic `^java.util.List` type-hint instead of `^LastTransactions`. In this case, any use of wrong `lastTransactions` in the body of the function will fail with `ClassCastException`. However, it won't check the type of elements in that list. To do so, use type hinting everytime you work with elements of `lastTransactions`.

**Example 1 with type hinting**:

```
(defn can-authorize
  [^Transaction transaction, ^java.util.List lastTransactions]
  (.size lastTransactions) 
)
```

In this case, decompiled java code will look like:

```
// Decompiling class: user$can_authorize
import clojure.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public final class user$can_authorize extends AFunction
{
    public static Object invokeStatic(final Object transaction, Object lastTransactions) {
        final Object o = lastTransactions;
        lastTransactions = null;
        return ((List)o).size();
    }

    public Object invoke(final Object transaction, final Object lastTransactions) {
        return invokeStatic(transaction, lastTransactions);
    }
}
```

**Example 2 without type hinting**:

```
(defn can-authorize [^String transaction,  lastTransactions]
             (.size lastTransactions))
```

decompiled to:

```
// Decompiling class: user$can_authorize
import clojure.lang.*;

public final class user$can_authorize extends AFunction
{
    public static Object invokeStatic(final Object transaction, Object lastTransactions) {
        final Object target = lastTransactions;
        lastTransactions = null;
        return Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(target, "size", false);
    }

    public Object invoke(final Object transaction, final Object lastTransactions) {
        return invokeStatic(transaction, lastTransactions);
    }
}
```

***Compare the resulted return statements:***

**with type hinting**

```
return ((List)o).size();
```

**without type hinting**

```
return Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(target, "size", false);
```

PS: code decompiled by using [clj-java-decompiler](https://github.com/clojure-goes-fast/clj-java-decompiler)